# socialService find method implementation

Tags: authentication, authorization, securesocial

I'm trying to apply Social Service 2.1.3 to my app (play framework). I have hard time with find method implementation. Right now (in save) method (after user login) i'm putting user Identity obj. to play cache (to avoid overusege of rest api that i'm useing). But it dose not work in the way I wont to.

When user logout from google account my app miss this event, user can still operate and manipulate with data. How can i get to information about current status of user login/logout. I thought about event listener or AuthenticatorStore but cant find any examples how to use it.

best regards 
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

SecureSocial can't detect if a user logs out from an external service such as Google or Facebook.

When a user logs into your app SecureSocial will ask the external service to perform authentication.  If successful the module will create an Authenticator to track that authenticated session.

The event listener works for actions done against SecureSocial itself, not the external providers.

Comment: Thanks for replay!, But how to logout from app with external provider?

Comment: you don't use the external provider to log out from your app. You have to use the logout functionality within SecureSocial that will close the authenticated session for your app only

Comment: so if im loggedin with google account on another web browser tab, there is no way to log out  and login with another account. in my case user is automatically logged with currently used account

Comment: you can tell Google to show the consent page again if you pass extra parameters to the authorization endpoint. See here for more information: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#re-consent